# Error when creating Xamarin.Android project in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I created new android project and, after building it, got error: "aapt.exe" exited with code -1073741819 and "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" do not exist. I really don't know what to do, because i didn't even do anything, just created it. I reinstalled everything, even xamarin for vs and android SDK. Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be few reasons for this error.

1. First ensure that you have not added any files to the resources folder. You have mentioned its a brand new project and , so I assume , you have not. But in case, please ensure to remove the hyphen from the files names.
2. Please update to the latest version on Xamarin. Goto Tools menu  -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Click on "check updates" and ensure the latest Xamarin sdk has been installed.
3. Now ensure all the android component are installed. Again , Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings and ensure that JDK, SDK and NDK are correctly set and they have a green tick mark.
4. Finally Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager, and ensure that the Android SDK Platform has been installed for the API level that you targetting. (this is more of a sanity check).

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Checked everything... Still got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created/ rename any filename with "-" in your "drawable" folder.